# Angular File Replacement Not Using Correct Environment

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, bitbucket

I am currently trying to set up a Release Process to Deploy an Angular App to Heroku via Bitbucket.
I tried to use file replacement to use a different apiUrl for different environments.

There are three environments

1. Production
2. Staging
3. Development

For these I created three files

1. environment.production.ts
2. environment.staging.ts
3. environment.ts

When I run `ng serve` locally it is as expected using the Development Environment and using the link from environment.ts

When I try to deploy to Staging the Bitbucket Pipeline runs `npm run build --staging`.
In this case however it is using environment.production.ts - which is set to be default - instead of environment.staging.ts.

Below is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "innovaticks": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en",
        "locales": {
          "de": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf"
        }
      },
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "localize": [
              "en"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/images",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/images"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/main.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/draw/draw.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/draw/shapes/line.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/draw/shapes/rectangle.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/draw/shapes/section.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/draw/shapes/text.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/math/mathHelper.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/move/move.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/selection/selection.js",
              "src/assets/modules/location_manager_customer/js/zoom/zoom.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "120kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "innovaticks:build:production"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "innovaticks:build:staging"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "innovaticks:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "innovaticks:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am quite new with Angular so I will appreciate if someone could help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Should be `ng build --configuration=staging`

Comment: @AndrewAllen When using Bitbucket I don't have the Angular CLI. Is there a way to do it with npm? Shouldn't it be the same when using npm run build --staging?

Comment: Not familiar with bitbucket to be able to advise. "staging" isn't a parameter of the angular build script so `--staging` is just getting ignored, hence why the default is used. `npm run build --configuration=staging` *might* work